# Trying to model with object-oriented javascript

Tags: javascript, oop

I am pretty new to the whole object-oriented paradigm.

I am trying to model a character in a certain game, you have different levels, classes, and lots of equipment choices and such.

My goal in the end would be to create a "dresser" of some sort where players could open up the site, try on some equips and see how it influence their parameters, how much it would cost, etc.

I already have the main parts programmed ([here](http://sylindrical.tumblr.com/lit)), but it was my first piece of work with html, css and javascript and it's just a whole big mess at the moment. 
I want to start out properly this time :)

---

Suppose I have an object for the character that we will be simulating:

```
var Lord = function(){

    this.Level =       1;
    this.Gender =      'Male';
    this.Faction =     'Knight';

    this.Attack =      0;
    this.Defense =     1;
    this.SpellPower =  0;
    this.Knowledge =   0;
    this.Luck =        0;
    this.Morale =      1;
    this.Initiative =  0;

    this.addParameter = function(Parameter, amount){
        this[Parameter] += amount;
    };
    this.changeLevelTo = function(Level){
        this.Level = Level;
    };
    this.changeGenderTo = function(Gender){
        this.Gender = Gender;
    };
    this.changeFactionTo = function(Faction){
        this.Faction = Faction;
        //adjust default stats based on new faction
    };
};
```

My problem is this:
A knight starts out with 1 Defense and 1 morale, different factions will give you different stat boosts. These values cannot be reallocated.
A player also gains some stat points to spend on different parameters upon leveling and these can be reallocated.

Furthermore, a player may equip some equipments that give stat boosts, and these cannot be reallocated as well (only by unequiping it).

What I've done previously is that I created a whole bunch of arrays all with their indices corresponding to each of the parameters, each array representing the default stat boost from different factions, the total stat boost from equipments, and the stats the player allocated manually. 
I then sum each of the indices to give me a final array of parameters to display. A player can then only reallocate points in the 3rd array, and not any other arrays.

How should I go about implementing this using object-oriented programming?

I've read up on some of the fundamental concepts (encapsulation, inheritance, polymorphism) but they are rather abstract and when I get down to it, I don't really know quite what to do :s

-

-

---

**Responses**

---

This webstie is quite hard to use :o

Ok, I'll try and see what I can get from qternion's answer:

```
var Faction = function(atk, def, sp, kn, luk, mor, ini){
    this.Attack =      atk;
    this.Defense =     def;
    this.SpellPower =  sp;
    this.Knowledge =   kn;
    this.Luck =        luk;
    this.Morale =      mor;
    this.Initiative =  ini;
}

var Knight = new Faction(0,1,0,0,0,1,0);
var Wizard = new Faction(0,0,0,1,0,1,0);
```

Then on the Lord object, I would have

```
    //this.Faction = 'Knight'
    this.Faction = Knight

    this.Defense = function(){
        return this.Faction.Defense + this.someOtherClass.Defense;
    }
```

---

I'll be looking to improve the above with prototypes using http://javascript.crockford.com/prototypal.html

Thanks to everyone for all of your contributions :)

Comment: `A knight starts out with 1 Defense` - so set this to 1 in your object literal ... `Defense:     0,` => `Defense:     1,`

Comment: In the spirit of wanting to increase your Javascript OO skills, you may also want to look at this SO post about prototyping functions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12238103/javascript-prototype-vs-general-functions-performance-readability

Comment: Since you're absolutely new to object-oriented programming I highly recommend that you read the following blog post about why prototypal inheritance matters: http://aaditmshah.github.io/why-prototypal-inheritance-matters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have your stats values be methods instead of member variables. That way, you could compute during the call a given stat, for exemple knight.defense(). In turn, the method defense() in your character class could call defense() from the faction class, defense() from the equipmentSet class, etc. The advantage of this is you could add additional stat modifiers whenever, for example if you decide you want a perk system or something.

Each faction class could then override their defense() function for their modifier.

I wouldn't call this the most object-oriented way but that's how I'd do it myself as a Javascript programmer.

Addendum: Pluto's answer is also how you get "classes" (instead of individual objects) that are reusable. As mentioned I'd also make Faction a class instead of just a string (you can type-check with instanceof):

```
var Faction = function (){
    this.prototype.defense = function () { return this.Defense; };
    this.prototype.initStats = function () { this.Defense = 0;};
    this.initStats(this);
};

var Knight = new Faction ();
Knight.prototype.initStats = function () { this.Defense = 1;};
```

For example.

Comment: ok wait, so since I am going to compute the defense anyway before presenting it, I can just use the return value of the defense method instead of computing it, assigning it to the defense property, and then use the property itself? I think I am starting to get this a little now :D

Comment: Yes, that's it. You only need to assign the return value manually if you want to cache it for some reason (for example you might have temporary stat modifications and you want to cache the character's base defense for some other checks).

Comment: emm, I am going to edit soon so it's visible in my first post above, but right now, I have an object for each faction and each one would have the corresponding property for each parameters. Then it gets kinda clumsy D:

Comment: ahh, forget the above, I just realised that I can just make a faction object, and then have each individual faction be an instantiation of that object! thanks, I think I have a firmer grip on this now :D

Comment: Yeah, I edited to explain how you can use inheritance to do that, which is at least clearer.

Comment: hmm, I still need to look at the prototype stuff :s

but if .defense in Knight is also a method, then it can potentially take care of other modifiers that may add on to it right?

Comment: Yeah, you could propagate modifiers where it's more appropriate. For example, if a given character has a faction modifier (given by Faction.defense()) and an equipment modifier and maybe some temporary status modifiers, then all those would be added up in the character's defense method. But if say, a faction's modifier can be impacted by a reputation meter or something, then you'd want knight.defense() to not just return its static modifier, but modify it according to its reputation value.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33923/discussion-between-sylin-and-qternion)

Answer (score 2):

You could keep your arrays if you want. The most important thing about object-oriented programming is **encapsulation**, which boils down to providing a means of interacting with your Character object without having to know anything whatsoever about the low-level implementation. You want to deal with **objects**, not arrays or hashtables (even if underneath it all, that's how the object is actually built!) What you want is to write code that looks like this :

```
var link = Knight();
link.equip(new MasterSword());
alert(link.getAttackPoints());
```

Eh, @qternion kind of beat me to it. So I'm turning this answer into a wiki ! Let's unleash the wisdom of SO on this one.

Comment: I am not quite sure what answer2wiki implies, but if it helps you and me, then I am fine with it :)

Answer (score 2):

Simply change Lord to be a function (ie. `var Lord = function() { /* current code */ }`) and set its properties with `this.Level = 1;`. Then from now on, you can create as many Lords as you want with `new Lord()` like most object-oriented programming languages.

An example of this in practice...

```
var Lord = function() {

    this.Level=1;
    this.Gender='Male';
    this.Faction='Knight';

    /* ... */

    this.addParameter=function(Parameter, amount){
        this[Parameter] += amount;
    };

    /* ... */
};
var a=new Lord();
var b=new Lord();
```

Comment: ok, perhaps I'll change to this

I was planning to use this notation for equipments etc, and there'll only be one character to dress around with so I used the literal notation, but I wasn't quite familiar with it